# Tensorflow Summary Scalar is not being displayed

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the following code to produce scalar graphs for my accuracy and cost, but the scalar summaries are not being displayed at the tensorboard. It gives me an error saying `No scalar data was found`. Can someone have a look please? code for the model:

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

    with tf.name_scope("cost"):
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(cost)
        tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('C:/Thesis/Conv3d/69', sess.graph)
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        successful_runs = 0
        total_runs = 0

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for data in train_data:
                total_runs += 1
                try:
                    X = data[0]


                    Y = data[1]
                    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})
                    writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=epoch)
                    epoch_loss += c

                    successful_runs += 1

                except Exception as e:

                    pass

            print('Epoch', epoch + 1, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)
            with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
                correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
                accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
                tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)



            print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: [i[0] for i in validation_data], y: [i[1] for i in validation_data]}))
        print('Done. Finishing accuracy:')
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: [i[0] for i in validation_data], y: [i[1] for i in validation_data]}))


        print('fitment percent:', successful_runs / total_runs)
```

Comment: This code is broken, you never define the `summary` variable anywhere.

Comment: @xdurch0 Thanks! I have added `_, c, summary = sess.run([optimizer, cost, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})` But I am still not able to generate graph.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `merge_all` *after* defining the summary ops. What happens right now is that the op simply doesn't have anything to summarize (since it's called first) and unfortunately isn't "smart" enough to add summary ops that are defined later.

Note that I also "fixed" the code in that you generally shouldn't run TF ops in a loop; I moved all the accuracy stuff before the training loop.

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)

    with tf.name_scope("cost"):
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(cost)
        tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)

    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('C:/Thesis/Conv3d/69', sess.graph)
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        successful_runs = 0
        total_runs = 0

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for data in train_data:
                total_runs += 1
                try:
                    X = data[0]


                    Y = data[1]
                    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})
                    writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=epoch)
                    epoch_loss += c

                    successful_runs += 1

                except Exception as e:

                    pass

            print('Epoch', epoch + 1, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

            print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: [i[0] for i in validation_data], y: [i[1] for i in validation_data]}))
        print('Done. Finishing accuracy:')
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: [i[0] for i in validation_data], y: [i[1] for i in validation_data]}))


        print('fitment percent:', successful_runs / total_runs)
```

Comment: Tensorboard still displays only one summary "Cost", and not "accuracy". It's still not merging the accuracy summary, plus for when defining the `tf.name_scope` outside the loop results in `loss = 0`. Thanks for your help though.